# SQL - Running of SP sums the first row as NULL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to develop a SP for Transaction operation , The SP gets as parameters the Username of the player , The Transaction amount,  and the Type of the Transaction if it's Deposit / Draw .

My problem is when the first row enters to the table my TotalAmount column in the tables the sums the total amount by Username starts from NULL for each username instead of the first deposit .
From the second row to the same username it's sums the total amount fine .

The SP -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RmW2.png

The Problem -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYTSx.png

Thanks!

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and edit your question and replace the images

Comment: Please don't use (links to) images for code, data or error messages, always use formatted text. As for the problem, NULL is unknown, so when you add it to something, the result is also unknown.

Comment: Here is the problem -- you are asking us to help you (for free) and you can't even be bothered to to put the code in the question to make it slightly easy to work on your problem.  It is just impolite honestly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have code like this :

```
 SET @TotalAMT = (@TransactionAMT + ( ... some code here))
```

Change it like this

```
 SET @TotalAMT = (@TransactionAMT + COALESCE( ... some code here), 0)
```